# How To Use Character " In indexOf() Android Java

Tags: java, android, character, substring, indexof

How to use a character like this " in a context like this.

```
String s;

answer = s.substring(s.indexOf("Start:"), s.indexOf("""));
```

When I use a word like ("stop"); or something (if the word stop is in the string!) it works perfect. But I want you read from ("Start:"), till the character ".

How can I set the character in the indexOf?

Comment: You have to escape the character: `"\""`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search

```
answer = s.substring(s.indexOf("Start:"), s.indexOf("\""));
```

in place of

```
answer = s.substring(s.indexOf("Start:"), s.indexOf("""));
```

`\` can be used to escape quotations or apostrophe.

Comment: answer = s.substring(s.indexOf("src="), s.indexOf("\"") + 1); my textview only display: src=" but between the Start: and " is normally more text? (an url).

Comment: Can you paste the `String` here?

Comment: <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Ek9fUXDqOO" height="259" width="460" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe> I wanna show the youtube url in my textview.

Comment: Try `answer = s.substring(s.indexOf("src=\""), s.indexOf("\"") + 1);`

Comment: Still the same textview.. :-( When I change the \" for height, the textview is ok. But I wanna use the "

Comment: When I use this: answer = s.substring(s.indexOf("src=") + 7, s.indexOf("height") - 2); then answer is: www.youtube.com/embed/Ek9fUXDqOO But I don't wanna use "height" but the " on the end of the url. :-)

Comment: Try `answer = s.substring(s.indexOf("src=\""), s.indexOf("\"",s.indexOf("\"")+1) + 1);`

Comment: Your awesome! This is what I use now.. answer = s.substring(s.indexOf("src=\"") + 7, s.indexOf("\"",s.indexOf("\"") + 1)); I changed it a bit, and work perfect now. (With your last comment the scr=" were visible to.. With this code now, only the url) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `\` to escape the double quote.

For instance:

```
s.indexOf("\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this `\` for escaping double quote

```
s.indexOf("\"");
```